# What address should I key in when using a friend's credit card?

Tags: credit-card, india, international, australia

I am from India. I am registering for an academic conference taking place in Australia. My credit card doesn't allow international transactions, so I am paying the conference registration fee using a friend's card.

At the point of payment, I get a [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQuES.png) that asks for information under three headings:

1. Customer Details (Name, Address, Contact No.)
2. Shipping Details (Name, Address, Contact No.)
3. Credit Card Details (Name, Card No.)

From what I understand, there is usually a billing details section, and the information under this needs to tally with the credit card information on the issuer's file. However, in this case there is no 'Billing Details' heading here. So, should I:

1. **Key in my friend's details under 'Customer Details'?** The problem here is, he is not the customer, I am.
2. **Key in my details under both Customer and Shipping details sections?** The problem here being, there is the risk the transaction gets flagged (and maybe declined?) later.

What do I do here?

Comment: In this case, I would put in YOUR name and HIS address in the Customer Details section, and YOUR address in the Shipping Details section.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Customer Details (Name, Address, Contact No.)
> 2. Shipping Details (Name, Address, Contact No.)
> 3. Credit Card Details (Name, Card No.)

Normally the credit card wants to know the billing address, to match their records. The vendor wants to know the shipping address, which doesn't have to match the billing address.

> I am registering for an academic conference taking place in Australia.
> My credit card doesn't allow international transactions, so I am
> paying the conference registration fee using a friend's card.

Make sure that your address is in the Shipping address because the conference organizer may be sending you stuff before the conference. You are also the customer so they want to make your name badge in advance.

So it should be:

1. Customer Details (Your name, Friend Address, Contact No.)
2. Shipping Details (Your Name, Your Address, Contact No.)
3. Credit Card Details (Friend Name, Card No.)

Think of the situation if the boss was paying for three of you to go on the company credit card; it would be a mix of the employee and the company information. The goal is to avoid having all three names badges say MR. Big software company.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of entering an address tied to a credit card is making sure the *address* matches what's on file - specifically the numbers.  The name is just for records and isn't actually checked (except sometimes for American Express cards).  As far as the industry is concerned, no one cares that you're entering the details instead of your friend.  It's his card, and so therefore he's the customer paying for it and you have to use his address.  You're right that it's usually termed the "billing address", but since there's also a place to enter a shipping address, it's clear that the "customer" is supposed to be the one who gets the bill.

Alternatively, if you're not comfortable with that, just ask the friend to register on your behalf. As an academic conference, I'm sure that many attendees will have had someone else from their lab or an administrative assistant actually fill it out on their behalf using an institutional credit card and address, so that would be perfectly normal.